# OAuth Failing when Creating Blog Post on Tumblr (Keep getting 401/not authorized)

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, tumblr

I keep getting 401 / not authorized from Tumblr when trying to create a [new blog posting](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting).

Here is the sequence of HTTP traffic I captured from my network card:

From Client to Tumblr:

> POST /v2/blog/topictastic.tumblr.com/post HTTP/1.1
>   Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="s83rTQBomoPtl66AT0hEScmYM0QYdhlbW0sa5sRIojgeGOcAUr", oauth_nonce="9313743", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1344973847", oauth_token="kw5NdFnuJ8CLC4cMOMJ4YsKXtOApdw6IcSoPJlF5GZgHaWo9zy", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="FLStmGNNdfhQysKDtcKSWFBY%2F%2F4%3D"
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Host: api.tumblr.com
>   Content-Length: 130
>   Expect: 100-continue
>   Connection: Keep-Alive

Response from Tumblr:

> HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

From Client to Tumblr:

> type=quote&quote=Taking+Input+in+C%2b%2b+without+Library+Functions&source=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f11959696%2f

Response from Tumblr:

> HTTP/1.1 401 Not Authorized
>   Date: Tue, 14 Aug 2012 19:50:56 GMT
>   Server: Apache
>   P3P: CP="ALL ADM DEV PSAi COM OUR OTRo STP IND ONL"
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding
>   X-Tumblr-Usec: D=293868
>   Content-Length: 60
>   Connection: close
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   {"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}

This is the C# source code I'm using to generate and post the request:

```
var baseHostName = request.Endpoint.Properties["base-hostname"];
var postUrl = string.Format("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{0}/post", baseHostName);
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    var oauth = new OAuthBase();
    var consumerKey = request.ApplicationProperties["ConsumerKey"];
    var consumerSecret = request.ApplicationProperties["ConsumerSecret"];
    var oauthToken = request.Enrollment.Properties["oauth_token"];
    var oauthTokenSecret = request.Enrollment.Properties["oauth_token_secret"];
    var timestamp = oauth.GenerateTimeStamp();
    var nonce = oauth.GenerateNonce();
    string url, url2;
    var values = new NameValueCollection();
    var type = request.Notification.Properties["type"];
    foreach (var property in request.Notification.Properties)
    {
        if (property.Key.StartsWith(type + "."))
        {
            var tumblrPropertyName = property.Key.Replace(type + ".", string.Empty);
            values.Add(tumblrPropertyName, property.Value);
        }
        else if (!property.Key.Contains("."))
        {
            values.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
        }
    }
    var postUri = new Uri(postUrl);
    var signature = oauth.GenerateSignature(
        postUri,
        consumerKey,
        consumerSecret,
        oauthToken,
        oauthTokenSecret,
        "POST",
        timestamp,
        nonce,
        null,
        out url,
        out url2);
    var urlEncodedSignature = oauth.UrlEncode(signature);
    var authHeader = "OAuth " + url2 + "&oauth_signature=" + urlEncodedSignature + "\"";
    authHeader = authHeader.Replace("&", "\", ").Replace("=", "=\"");
    wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
    try
    {
        wc.UploadValues(postUri, values);
    }
    catch (WebException webException)
    {
        var message = (new StreamReader(webException.Response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
        throw new Exception(message, webException);
    }
}
```

The `OAuthBase` class is [located here](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/csharp/OAuthBase.cs).

I do have a valid oauth_token and oauth_token_secret at the point I'm running this code.
Any ideas what's wrong with this? Why do I keep getting 401/not authroized?

Comment: did you get any resolution for the same? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem (but with iOS): it seems like the OAuth library I used was not using the POST Data fields for the signature. After I've added the fields **type** and **caption** additionally as a query string, the OAuth library used them and I was able to upload a photo/post/whatever.

Seems like every post body field (except for the binary data) needs to be part of the OAuth signature.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to change your encoding.  For example spaces should be "%20" rather than "+" symbols!